# How do i extract a list of elements encased in quotation marks bounded by <> and delimited by commas - python, regex?

Tags: python, regex, string, brackets

Given a string like this:

```
ORTH < "cali.ber,kl", 'calf' , "done" >,\nLKEYS.KEYREL.PRED "_calf_n_1_rel",
```

With regex, how do I get a tuple that looks like the following:

```
('ORTH', ['cali.ber,kl','calf','done'])
```

I've been doing it as such:

```
txt = '''ORTH < "cali.ber,kl", 'calf' , "done" >,'''
e1 = txt.partition(" ")[0]
vs = re.search(r"<([A-Za-z0-9_]+)>", txt)
v = vs.group(1)
v1 = [i[1:-1] for i in vs.strip().strip("<>").split(",")]
print v1
```

But i'm getting none for `re.search().group(1)`. How should it be done to get the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you don't get a match is that your regex doesn't match:

`r"<([A-Za-z0-9_]+)>"` is missing comma, quotation marks and the space character, which all can occur inside the `< >` according to your sample.

This one would match:

```
re.search(r"< ([A-Za-z0-9_.,\"' ]+) >", txt)
```

What also may trip you up is the fact that the list of names is delimited by comma, which itself can be part of the *values*, unescaped.

That means you can't just split that string by `','`, but instead need to consider the two different quotation characters(`'` and `"` ) in order to separate the fields.

So I'd use this approach:

- Use `re.match` to split the string into PREFIX < NAMES > parts, and discard the rest.
- Use `re.findall()` to split the names into fields according to quotation marks

## Edit:

**1)** According to your first comment, your data can also contain a preamble before the prefix *that contains newlines*. The default behavior for `.` is [to match everything *except newlines*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL).

From the Python `re` docs:

> `re.DOTALL`
>
> Make the `'.'` special character match any character at all, including a newline; without this flag, `'.'` will match anything except a newline.

So you need to construct that regex with the `re.DOTALL` flag. You do this by compiling it first and passing the `OR`ed flags:

```
re.compile(pattern, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

**2)** If you include the space character before `PREFIX` in the regex, it will only match for data that actually contains that space - but not anymore for your first piece of example data. So I use `.*?([A-Z\.]*)...` to cover both cases. The `?` is for non-greedy matching, so it matches the shortest possible match instead of the longest.

**3)** To cover `PREFIX.FOO` just extend the pattern for the prefix to `([A-Z\.]*)` by including the `.` character and escaping it.

Updated example covering all the cases you mentioned:

```
import re

TEST_VALUES = [
    """ORTH.FOO < "cali.ber,kl", 'calf' , "done" >,\nLKEYS.KEYREL.PRED "_calf_n_1_rel",""",
    """calf_n1 := n_-_c_le & n_-_pn_le &\n [ ORTH.FOO < "cali.ber,kl", 'calf' , "done" >,\nLKEYS.KEYREL.PRED "_calf_n_1_rel","""
]

EXPECTED = ('ORTH.FOO', ['cali.ber,kl','calf','done'])


pattern = re.compile(r'.*?([A-Z\.]*) < (.*) >.*', flags=re.DOTALL)


for value in TEST_VALUES:
    prefix, names_str = pattern.match(value).groups()
    names = re.findall('[\'"](.*?)["\']', names_str)

    result = prefix, names
    assert(result == EXPECTED)

print result
```

Comment: Thanks, the regex works for the given string above but it's not working for my data because i had some other chars before the prefix, e.g. `"""calf_n1 := n_-_c_le & n_-_pn_le &\n [ ORTH < "cali.ber,kl", 'calf' , "done" >,\nLKEYS.KEYREL.PRED "_calf_n_1_rel","""`. I've tried to catch the pattern with `r'.* ([A-Z]*) < (.*) >.*'` but it isn't working too =(

Comment: sometimes my data gives `"""calf_n1 := n_-_c_le & n_-_pn_le &\n [ PHON.POO "whatever",\n ORTH < "cali.ber,kl", 'calf' , "done" >,\nLKEYS.KEYREL.PRED "_calf_n_1_rel","""` too...

Comment: i don't mind catching `('PHON.POO', 'whatever')` in the `(prefix, name_str)` but i can't seem to be getting the `CAPS.PREFIX < 'x', "y">`

Comment: @2er0 updated my answer to cover the additional cases you provided.

Comment: Thanks the `re.DOTALL` flag does the thing =)